# Counting the number of inversions in merge sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, inversion

I have implemented a merge sort and, as well as sorting, I would like it to  compute the number of [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)) in the original array.

Below is my attempt at implementing it, which for some reason doesn't compute the number of inversions correctly.

For example, `mergeSort([4, 3, 2, 1])` should return `(6, [1, 2, 3, 4])`.

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    count = 0  
    if len(alist)>1:
        mid = len(alist)//2
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]

        mergeSort(lefthalf)
        mergeSort(righthalf)

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0

        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                count +=len(lefthalf[i:])
                j=j+1    
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf):
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1   

   return count, alist
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are calling "inversion", please?

Comment: The number of changes necessary to order an array.

Comment: The indentation is wrong.  That makes it hard to run this. Looking at it.

Comment: What do you mean by a change? Which operations specifically are you trying to count? Mergesort does not use a "swap" operation. It uses a "merge" operation. E.g. if you merge `[3]` and `[1 4]`, you get `[1, 3, 4]`. So do you count item comparisons (there's just one between 1 and 3), inserts (there are three), or merges (this would be a single merge)?

Comment: For instance, having the array [1,3,2], if we want order you need to swap (3,2). So you will have one inversion.

Comment: Quit asking what an inversion is. Click on the tag for a definition. It's a well defined term from any intro algorithms text.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's not exactly "the number of changes necessary to order an array" as OP said. `4, 3, 2, 1` has an inversion number of 6 `{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)}`, but you only need 2 changes to sort the list: `(1, 4)` and `(2, 3)`. That's why I asked what OP meant by "change".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was not including the counts of sorting left and right sides.

```
def mergeSort(alist):
    count = 0
    leftcount = 0
    rightcount = 0
    blist = [] 
    if len(alist) > 1:
       mid = len(alist) // 2
       lefthalf = alist[:mid]
       righthalf = alist[mid:]
       leftcount, lefthalf = mergeSort(lefthalf)
       rightcount, righthalf = mergeSort(righthalf)

       i = 0
       j = 0

       while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
         if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
             blist.append(lefthalf[i])
             i += 1
         else:
             blist.append(righthalf[j])
             j += 1
             count += len(lefthalf[i:])

       while i < len(lefthalf):
          blist.append(lefthalf[i])
          i += 1

       while j < len(righthalf):
          blist.append(righthalf[j])
          j += 1
    else:
        blist = alist[:]

    return count + leftcount + rightcount, blist
```

Comment: I am trying to count the number of changes necessary to order an array

Comment: Can you specify what counts as a change in merge sort (and give an example)? Some algorithms use a "swap" function, but merge sort doesn't. If you're trying to count the number of items that changed positions, maybe you could do that separately: first, sort the list and then compare each item of the new array with the original.

Comment: For instance, having the array [1,3,2], if we want order you need to swap (3,2). So you will have one inversion.

Comment: You solved my problem. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a tuple of (inversion, sortedlist). However your internal recursive calls completely disregard this, so any inversions you count below the top level are simply tossed aside and not counted.

```
  lc, lefthalf = mergeSort(alist[:mid])
  rc, righthalf = mergeSort(alist[mid:])
  count = count + lc + rc
```

and if you share this with classmates, you may use this:

```
def count_inversions(data):
    count, result = mergeSort(data)
    return count

test_cases = [
    (3, [1,3,5,2,4,6]),
    (590, [37, 7, 2, 14, 35, 47, 10, 24, 44, 17, 34, 11, 16, 48, 1, 39, 6, 33, 43, 26, 40, 4, 28, 5, 38, 41, 42, 12, 13, 21, 29, 18, 3, 19, 0, 32, 46, 27, 31, 25, 15, 36, 20, 8, 9, 49, 22, 23, 30, 45]),
    (2372, [4, 80, 70, 23, 9, 60, 68, 27, 66, 78, 12, 40, 52, 53, 44, 8, 49, 28, 18, 46, 21, 39, 51, 7, 87, 99, 69, 62, 84, 6, 79, 67, 14, 98, 83, 0, 96, 5, 82, 10, 26, 48, 3, 2, 15, 92, 11, 55, 63, 97, 43, 45, 81, 42, 95, 20, 25, 74, 24, 72, 91, 35, 86, 19, 75, 58, 71, 47, 76, 59, 64, 93, 17, 50, 56, 94, 90, 89, 32, 37, 34, 65, 1, 73, 41, 36, 57, 77, 30, 22, 13, 29, 38, 16, 88, 61, 31, 85, 33, 54]),
]

def validate():
    for expected, data in test_cases:
        answer = count_inversions(data)
        if answer != expected:
            print "FAILED VALIDATION -- actual:", answer, "expected:", expected, "data:", data

validate()
```

Comment: Hmm. That must be old. I usually raise ValueError on a failed test case.